# How can I get past canvas's maximum line limitation?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, line

I have http://deck.net/4488411c38b84b496a79f7eafb877a25 and when I type sides 3, number 200. It doesn't generate the whole thing. I want it to and am wondering if there is anyway of stopping this from happenning?

I am using Bridge though so here's my bridge code:

```
context.BeginPath();
    context.MoveTo(pos.X, pos.Y);
    for (int n = 0; n < nShapes; n++)
    {
        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < sides; n2++)
        {
            pos.X += (Math.Sin(direction * (Math.PI/180)) * sidesLength);
            pos.Y += (Math.Cos(direction * (Math.PI/180)) * sidesLength);
            context.LineTo(pos.X, pos.Y);
            direction += (360 / sides);
            direction %= 360;
        }
        direction += 360/nShapes;
    }
    context.Stroke();
}
```

Here's the javascript:

```
context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
            for (var n = 0; n < Demo.Program.nShapes; n = (n + 1) | 0) {
                for (var n2 = 0; n2 < Demo.Program.sides; n2 = (n2 + 1) | 0) {
                    pos.x += (Math.sin(direction * (Math.PI / 180)) * sidesLength);
                    pos.y += (Math.cos(direction * (Math.PI / 180)) * sidesLength);
                    context.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
                    direction += ((((Bridge.Int.div(360, Demo.Program.sides)) | 0))) | 0;
                    direction %= 360;
                }
                direction += (Bridge.Int.div(360, Demo.Program.nShapes)) | 0;
            }
            context.stroke();
```

Bridge.Int.div is the divide equivalent of c# for int (s).

Comment: Please don't post external link. Post the code where you've a problem.

Comment: OK, I will post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ints and Doubles don't mix well.

The problem is the types you are using. `sides` and `nShapes` are ints and `direction` is a `double` so when you add `direction += 360 / nShapes` the type casting does not happen till after the right hand side is done. `360/200 = 1.8` but as you are using int's the actual result is `360/200 = 1` thus you do not complete the 360, but still get 200 shapes.

To fix you just need to ensure the correct type on the right hand side.

```
direction = 360/(double)nShapes;  // Just need one double to force right 
                                  // side to the correct type
```

Or the alternative prefered way

```
direction = 360.0/nShapes; // adds without rounding down
```

The `.0` forces the value to be a `float` (`double` in the case of c#) and thus the right side of the line now has the correct type and there is no rounding error.